# script or addon to add animation tools button in the N properties?

Tags: animation, scripting, add-on

did anyone know what script or add-on to make new slide in the N properties and add the animation tools to these slide??

the simplify button is from scene tab properties
, the constant button is from user preference editing (new f-curve default)
, the red button and in/out box is from animation tools (start/end animation)

i think if there's a script or addon to make UI like this, it will help animator alot to save the work space.. btw sorry for my terrible eng

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### EDIT

Added [repository](https://github.com/LeanderSilur/Blender-Le-Animation-Tools). Can now be properly installed, activated and deactivated as an addon.
[image]

This script creates the desired section with other properties added.

```
import bpy

class anim_tools_ui(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_label = "Animation Tools"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_le_animation_tools_ui"
    
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        obj = context.object
        
        row = layout.row()
        row.prop(context.tool_settings, "use_keyframe_insert_auto", text="")
        row.prop(context.tool_settings, "keyframe_type", text="")
        row.operator("anim.keyframe_insert", text="", icon="KEY_HLT")
        row.operator("anim.keyframe_delete", text="", icon="KEY_DEHLT")
        row = layout.row()
        row.prop(context.user_preferences.edit, "keyframe_new_interpolation_type", text="")
        row.prop(context.user_preferences.edit, "keyframe_new_handle_type", text="")
        
        
        row = layout.row()
        row.separator()
        
        row = layout.row()
        row.label(text="Playback")
        row = layout.row()
        row.prop(context.scene, "sync_mode", text="")
        row.prop(context.scene, "frame_current", text="Frame")
        row.prop(context.scene.render, "fps", text="FPS")
        row = layout.row()
        row.prop(context.scene, "frame_start", text="Start")
        row.prop(context.scene, "frame_end", text="End")
        
        
        row = layout.row()
        row.separator()
        
        row = layout.row()
        row.prop(context.scene.render, "use_simplify", text="Simplify")
        row.prop(context.scene.render, "simplify_subdivision", text="levels")
        
        
        

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(anim_tools_ui)
    
def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(anim_tools_ui)
    
register()
```

It is important that after pasting the script in the text editor, the name of the text data block ends with "**.py**" and **Register** is checked.
[image]

#### Further Resources

[Building a UI Panel](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Py/Scripts/Cookbook/Code_snippets/Interface)

[Conversion into an addon](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_65_5/info_tutorial_addon.html)

Comment: wooaaaah THANKS, THANKS A LOT, it really help me.. now i can animate with better workspace size

mind if I share it? i think it will help other people too

Comment: Added a github link. Now you can install it as an addon. https://github.com/LeanderSilur/Blender-Le-Animation-Tools

Answer (score 0):

The addon was actually called Freen's Animation Tools and was included with CGCookies The Fundamentals of Animation course, with a name adjustment to match the rig name being used. That is the course that your screenshot is from. I am fairly sure that in one of the videos Beorn discussed the panel and how you can adjust it yourself.

My copy of it has been adjusted over time and I now have the following panel.

[image: Freens animation tools panel]

As it is released under GPL you can get a copy of it in [my github repo](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sambler/myblendercontrib/master/animation_freens_tools.py).